# Accessing self-defined Datatypes - Lambda function application order

Tags: haskell, lambda, types

Got this:

```
data Cmd = PushK Int | Pop | Push Int
         deriving (Eq,Show)

type StackProgram = [Cmd]
```

**Question:**
How can I access the `Int` value of `PushK`?

---

```
> head [PushK 5, Pop]
PushK 5  -- Great!

> (\_ x -> x)PushK 5
5 -- Great!

> (\_ x -> x)(head [PushK 5, Pop])
Couldn't match expected type `t1 -> t' with actual type `Cmd'
```

Anyone have a solution?

Comment: `(\_ x -> x)PushK 5` doesn't do what you think it does. The `_` is matched with `PushK`, and `x` is matched with `5`. Try `(\_ x -> x)(PushK 5)`, you'll see an error. What you probably mean is `(\(PushK x) -> x)(PushK 5)`

Comment: i know of the error that returns from: (\_ x -> x)(PushK 5) 
Tried to to ignore it but i guess its more relevant than i thought!

Answer (score 4):

You unwrap values out of a data constructor by using *pattern matching*, or by defining *record syntax* (in which case Haskell generates the getters itself).

## Pattern matching

Since here the type is *not* defined as record, we thus have to use pattern matching:

```
getK :: Cmd -> Int
getK (PushK x) = x
-- ...
```

and probably you need to handle the cases of another data constructor.

We can also perform this pattern matching with a lambda expression:

```
(\(PushK x) -> x) (PushK 5)
```

## Records

We can also define the command as a record:

```
data Cmd = PushK { k :: Int } | Pop | Push { p :: Int } deriving (Eq,Show)
```

Now Haskell has generated two functions `k :: Cmd -> Int` and `p :: Cmd -> Int` automatically, so in that case we can write:

```
k (PushK 5)
```

which will return `5`.

## Why did `(\_ x -> x) PushK 5` return `5`?

In Haskell functions are *first class citizens*. That means you can pass functions as arguments, return them as result. You here did *not* constructed a `Cmd`.

In fact `PushK` is a *data constructor*, and a function (with type `Int -> Cmd`), you thus called the lambda expression with *two* parameters: the first one is the `pushK`, and the second is `5`. You simply omit the first parameter, and retun the second `x`.

But it is thus derived as:

```
   (\y x -> x) PushK 5
=  ((\y -> (\x -> x)) PushK) 5    -- (more verbose version)
-> (\x -> x) 5
-> 5
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to define a single *catamorphism* to deconstruct an arbitrary `Cmd` value.

```
cmdCata :: (Int -> a)  -- Function to apply to x in (PushK x)
        -> a           -- Value to replace Pop
        -> (Int -> a)  -- Function to apply to x in (Push x)
        -> Cmd         -- The value to deconstruct
        -> a           -- The result
cmdCata f _ _ (PushK x) = f x
cmdCata _ x _ Pop       = x
cmdCata _ _ f (Push x)  = f x
```

It takes two functions and a default value (for `Pop`) to turn *any* `Cmd` value into a value of type `a`. The following extracts the value wrapped by `PushK` or `Push` and rewraps it with `Just` (the function for `PushK` doing a little extra work just to show the difference between `PushK` and `Push`), and replaces `Pop` with `Nothing`.

```
> cmdCata (Just . (+3)) Nothing Just (PushK 5)
Just 8  -- 5 + 3
> cmdCata (Just . (+3)) Nothing Just Pop
Nothing
> cmdCata (Just . (+3)) Nothing Just (Push 20)
Just 20
```

Or if you just want an integer and a default value for `Pop` is fine:

```
> cmdCata id 0 id (PushK 5)
5
> cmdCata id 0 id Pop
0
> cmdcata id 0 id (Push 3)
3
```

Compare `cmdCata` to `Data.Maybe.maybe`, and think of what functions analogous to `Data.Maybe.fromJust`, `Data.Maybe.catMaybes`, etc, could be defined for your `Cmd` type.